# Expression engine String manipulation

Tags: string, expressionengine

Any idea how to do advanced string manipulation in Expression Engine?

I tried to use php code inside expression engine template but I ask about if there is any another solution using expression engine,Or there is any plugin can support this feature?

Thanks

Comment: What are you specifically looking to do? There's a plugin for string manipulation here: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ce-string

Comment: I want to check if string contains another string

Comment: if(some string contains another string)
then do this

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [Streeng plugin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/streeng) will do what you need. Their example even does exactly what you're looking for:

```
{if "{exp:streeng find='this' insensitive='yes'}This is a test string{/exp:streeng}"}
    We found 'this' in 'This is a test string'!
{/if}
```

Just as a note, you can post EE-specific questions to [expressionengine.stackexchange.com](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com) and you might get more answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a plugin called ce string - by causing effect. http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-string

It has a whole range of string manipulation functions and is something I tend to use on all my Expression Engine projects for one reason or another.